# JQuery from google doesn't load properly and Script never runs

Tags: javascript, html, css

OK, so I'm starting to use JQuery and its going good but then after like 2:40hrs this comes up in the console

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Illegal break statement SyntaxError: Illegal break statement 
at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677)
```

but i only mention JQuery once in my code and it was working 5 mins ago and i haven't edited the html since then

```
<head>
    <title>My Free MinecraftServer</title>;
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">;
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js"></script>;
</head>
```

this is my html head.

```
function ExecureQuery ()
{
  var ValidQuery=true;
  var Query =window.location.search.substr(1).split("&");//return Query without '?' at start
  console.log("Query (",window.location.search.substr(1),")");

  if(Query .length > 1)
  {
    ValidQuery=false;
  }

  if(ValidQuery)
  {
    for(var x = 0; x < Query.length;x++)
    {
      if(Query[x].startsWith("hide="))
      {
        var hide = Query[x].substr(5);
      }
    }
  }

  if(hide === undefined)
  {
    hide = true;
  }

  if(ValidQuery)
  {
    if(hide == "true")
    {
      $("#hidden").replaceWith("");
      hide = true;
    }
    else if (hide == "false")
    {
      hide = false;
    }
    else
    {
      ValidQuery=false;
      break;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("InvalidQuery Triggerd");
    $( "body" ).replaceWith("<h1>WARNING:INVALID QUERY</h1><br><p>this could be a result of someone trying to inject stuff into this page.<br> IF YOU ARENT TESTING SECURITY:report this to the server admin and restart your browser because someone might be trying to hack you.<br>IF YOU ARE CHEACKING SECURITY:all i have to say is nice try, but not quite there.</p>");
  }
}
$(document).ready(ExecureQuery);
```

this is my JQuery/js

**What I tried:**

I looked in google, i tried to copy paste the error and then lookup "google JQuery Illegal break statement" it didn't come up with anything at all.

I looked if i had 2 references to the JQuery lib but no just the one in the head.
then i asked on dscord no one has replied yet.

more info:
this is the only script that is on the page.

what the script should do is 'hide' some of the page content unless I add "?hide=false" to the end of the URL.

I have only started JavaScript/JQuery since today and looked up all the functions and how to use them then edited them to suit my need like you would any new lang.

Comment: It's *JQuery not JQuary

Comment: oh ill fix that now thnx

Comment: You can't use the `break` keyword where you're trying to, try using `return` instead.

Comment: also your $(document).ready(ExecureQuary); and your function is called ExecureQuery check the spell on that one

Comment: thnx i changed all the "Quarys" to "Querys" because that was a spelling misstake

Comment: After you get your error sorted out, you're going to have other problems. `hide` is a Boolean, so you check it against the Boolean `true` and/or `false`, not the strings `"true"` and/or `"false"`. And, a Boolean can only be one of those two, so you only need and `if/else`, not an `if/else if/else`. Lastly, to test a Boolean, all you need is: `if(hide)`, you don't need to test it for `true` with `if(hide === true)`.

Comment: i know i changed that after some one pointed it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error fortunately is pretty clear about what's going on. Exceptions come from your Javascript — it's not an issue with your HTML or how you're including the script tag.

Based on the original code you posted before revising, you're using a `break` statement, but those are reserved for loops - for, while, switch, etc. Here's a snippet from the documentation on MDN:

> The break statement terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers program control to the statement following the terminated statement.
>   [Full documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

To fix this, just use return instead:

```
if(ValidQuery)
{
if(hide == "true")
{
  $("#hidden").replaceWith("");
  hide = true;
}
else if (hide == "false")
{
  hide = false;
}
else
{
  ValidQuery=false;
  return;
}
}
```

Comment: the problem is in your code but you still missed it.

Comment: hint.. hide is a boolean not a string

Comment: @ScottMarcus He removed it in a revision:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49016587/revisions

Comment: i copied the code from another file from a for loop and it removed the error + i changed it from "if(hint==true){ . . . }else if . . ." to "if(hint) { . . .} else { . . .}" but the code dosent hide all the tags

Comment: @baileydrahoss Well, that's a different issue. You should mark this answer as "the" answer, work on your new issue and post a new question if necessary.

Comment: @MaxGardner If you edit your question to clarify that the OP had `break` in an earlier version, I can remove my down vote.

Comment: i did a big screw up and forgot to remove some code after editing it and that lead me to thinking there was another problem

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for the recommendation to add that note. I edited my answer to clarify.